# How to interrupt dialog animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-alertdialog, fragment-animation

I have the Dialog fragment with dialog, that have such animation:

```
dialog.window.setWindowAnimations(R.style.RemoveWishlistAnimation)
```

In this style exit `animation` has long duration, so if user pressed HOME button, some part of animation will be shown on home screen.
I must use this long animation, but is it exists any way to interrupt this animation in some kind of `override fun onPause() {}` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your piece of code inside a handler as follows:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dialog.window.setWindowAnimations(R.style.RemoveWishlistAnimation);
            }
        }, 5000);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand, how this can help to interrupt an already running animation

Comment: @AleksandrGilmanov, If you engulf the piece of code within the handler, then animation will delay by 5 seconds. I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: I want to start animation after user make the choice - dialog is closing and starts animation that I set in `dialog.window.setWindowAnimations(R.style.RemoveWishlistAnimation);` But after animation started, and before animation ends user can press Home or Back button, and animation will be played on the home screen. It looks bad =( I hope to find way to interrupt this animation or hide.